# Existence of a global minimum of a set.

Tags: set-theory

I have a newbie question about set theory.

There is a mapping between the set of all strings (of finite length and alphabet) to the set of natural numbers:
                       $ F: \{a,b\}^* \to \mathbb{N} $. 
There is no additional information about the mapping.

It seems obvious that, for an arbitrary mapping, we cannot say that there exists a string s such that $\forall s_1: F(s) \geq F(s_1)$, because the function may be, for example, a mapping from strings to their lengths which go to infinity.

But, can we guarantee that there exists a string s such that $\forall s_1: F(s) \leq F(s_1)$? Which axiom or theorem allows us to make such an assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the [Well-Ordering Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) of $\mathbb{N}$: every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum element.  In the case you are describing, if $F : \{ a , b \}^* \to \mathbb{N}$, then the *range* of $F$, $$F [ \{ a , b \}^* ] = \{ F ( s ) : s \in \{ a , b \}^* \},$$ is nonempty, and thus has a minimum element, say $n$.  Any $s \in \{ a , b \}^*$ such that $F(s) = n$ will then work.

Answer (score 3):

The axiom you are after is the "Well ordering principle".  Every non-empty subset of the natural numbers has a least element.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle